# Is this a safe way to access an enum?

Tags: c#, class, static, enums, instantiation

My legacy code has this:

```
if (chgList != ABCHeader.ChangeListTypes.Always)
```

Here is ABCHeader - it's a class (not a variable), and is a non-static class at that:

```
public class ABCHeader
{
    . . .

     public enum ChangeListTypes
     {
    ...
     }
```

chgList is defined this way:

```
private ABCHeader.ChangeListTypes chgList = ABCHeader.ChangeListTypes.Always;
```

This obviously compiles, but it doesn't seem right to me that this non-static class (ABCHeader) is being referenced this way. As I've got a strange Null Reference Exception somewhere in this code, looking through the code I stumbled upon this. Is this a potential problem, or am I definitely barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Looks fine, you should put your assignment in the constructor, though

Comment: @bash.d, why should the assignment be in the constructor?

Comment: Merely a convention, usually you just assign const members this way.

Comment: @bash.d, um, no.  Initializing field values by using the [C# field initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx) is *very* standard.  (Often it precludes the need to even *have* a constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just *nested types*. A `class` (both static and non-static), or `struct`, can contain another type inside of it. The period `.` is a "static member" access. It's much like the period when you call a static method, say `ABCHeader.SomeMethod();`.

This kind of period can never lead to a `NullReferenceException` the way an instance member access period can.

Note that the .NET Framework uses plus `+` instead of period `.` to signify a nested type. For example:

```
string typeString = typeof(ABCHeader.ChangeListTypes).ToString();
    // will contain a name including "ABCHeader+ChangeListTypes"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this.  You access a nested enum inside of a class through the class name.

Now, that said, I prefer to have my enums at the top level, not nested inside of a class, but if that's how you want to do it that is the appropriate syntax for it.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine to reference the enum this way - you can't get a null reference exception from this.